# Where to start to optimize slow WP SQL query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance, query-optimization

I have the following query, which currently takes about 0.3s to load, causing a heavy load on my Wordpress site.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp11_posts.ID
FROM wp11_posts
WHERE 1=1
AND ( wp11_posts.ID NOT IN (
SELECT object_id
FROM wp11_term_relationships
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (137,141) )
AND (
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM wp11_term_relationships
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (53)
AND object_id = wp11_posts.ID ) = 1 )
AND wp11_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND ((wp11_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY wp11_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp11_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Where should I start to make it execute faster? Is there an apparent mistake standing out, that should definitely had been done differently?

Comment: The first thing I would do is to remove `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. It is a [well-known performance negative](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/). That single change may help, without changing any other part of the query. Also it is [deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

Comment: Next, change the correlated subquery to an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @BillKarwin - I suspect that removing the CALC won't help much _in this case_.  This is because the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` force the query to find _all_ the rows _and_ sort them before getting to the `LIMIT`.  (No index can possibly help.)

Comment: Did you write this query yourself, or did something in WordPress generate it for you? Please [edit] your question to tell us. And, somebody should tell the WordPress core team that `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is deprecated. I'll look for a tix and file one if there isn't one already.

Comment: Here is the [WordPress core tix](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47280). The feature is deprecated in Oracle MySQL but not in MariaDB.

Comment: @O.Jones The query is handled by the theme. I use the TagDiv Newspaper theme, and I have contacted their support team, and shared this thread link also. Perhaps it can be of help to bring this to their attention.

Answer (score 2):

You have a so-called **dependent subquery** (a/k/a correlated subquery) in your example. It's a performance killer.

```sql
        WHERE (
            SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM wp_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (53)
                AND object_id = wp_posts.ID
              ) = 1
```

Refactoring it to an independent subquery looks like this:

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
JOIN (
   SELECT object_id
     FROM wp_term_relationships
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (53)
    GROUP BY object_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
     ) justone  ON wp_posts.ID = justone.object_id
... WHERE ...
```

See how this works? It needs to scan `term_relationships` just one time looking for object_ids meeting your criterion (just one). Then the ordinary inner JOIN excludes `posts` rows that don't meet that criterion. (The dependent subquery loops to scan the table multiple times, while we wait.)

The **SQL_FOUND_ROWS thing**: WordPress puts it there to help with "pagination" -- it lets WordPress figure out how many pages (in your case of five items) there are to display. It provides data to the familiar

```
 987 Items <<  <   2 of [ 20 ]  >  >>
```

page-selection interface you see in many parts of WordPress: it counts all the items matched by your query (987 in this example), not just one pageload of them.

If you don't need that [pagination you can turn it off](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters) by giving a `'nopagination' => true` element to WP_Query(). But if your query only yields a small number of items *without* the LIMIT clause, this probably doesn't matter much. If you wrote the query yourself, just leave it out along with the ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses.

So, leaving in the pagination stuff, a better query is

```sql
ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON  SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
JOIN (
   SELECT object_id
     FROM wp_term_relationships
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (53)
    GROUP BY object_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
     ) justone  ON wp_posts.ID = justone.object_id
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND (
        wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
            SELECT object_id
            FROM wp_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (137,141)
            )
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

You also have an **unnecessary GROUP BY** near the end of your query. It doesn't hurt performance: MySQL can tell it's not needed in this case and doesn't do anything with it. But it is extra stuff. If you wrote the query yourself leave it out.

Comment: Wordpress is FULL of calls that need to be refactored. :(

Comment: @StephenFeather you are exactly right: WordPress needs lots of back end optimization. And the carbon-emission savings leverage from even small WordPress optimizations is very large.

Answer (score 1):

- `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` requires doing nearly as much work as the same query without the `LIMIT`.  [However, removing it without doing most of the following things probably won't help much.]
- Do you already have this plugin installed?  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/  If not, that may be a good starting point.
- WP is not designed to handle millions of posts/attributes/terms; you may have move on beyond WP.
- Using `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` or `[NOT] EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )` may be more efficient than `IN ( SELECT ... )`, especially in older versions of MySQL.
- Is your `SELECT  COUNT(1)` attempting to demand *exactly* 1?  That is, 2 would be disallowed?  If you really wanted to know if *any* exist, then use

  ```
  AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM wp11_term_relationships
                WHERE  term_taxonomy_id IN (53)
                  AND  object_id = wp11_posts.ID )`
  ```
- A better index for wp11_posts [I don't know whether your WP or the Plugin has this already]:

  ```
    INDEX(post_status, post_type,  -- first, either order is OK
          post_date, ID)           -- last, in this order
  ```
- Having the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` the 'same' may eliminate a sort.  The following change will probably give you the same results, but faster.

  ```
    GROUP BY  wp11_posts.ID
    ORDER BY  wp11_posts.post_date DESC
  ```

-->

```
    GROUP BY  wp11_posts.post_date,      wp11_posts.ID
    ORDER BY  wp11_posts.post_date DESC, wp11_posts.ID DESC
```

Comment: The standard [WordPress schema](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts) for `posts` does contain the appropriate index.